# Text Mining - removePunctuation not removing quotes and dashes

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I have been doing some text mining. I created the DTM matrix using the 
following steps.

```
corpus1<-VCorpus(VectorSource(resume1$Dat1)) 

corpus1<-tm_map(corpus1,content_transformer(tolower)) 
corpus1<-tm_map(corpus1,content_transformer(trimWhiteSpace))

dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(corpus1, 
                           control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE, 
                                          removeNumbers = TRUE, 
                                          removeSparseTerms=TRUE, 
                                            stopwords = TRUE))
```

​After all the run I am still getting words like -quotation, "fun, model"​ 
, etc in dtm.Also getting blanks like "        " in the data

What can I do about it? I do not need this dahses and extra quotations.

Comment: seems to me like a syntax or encoding issue. Please make sure you are using the encoding specified in your input file.

Comment: This is mentioned and solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994194/quotes-and-hyphens-not-removed-by-tm-package-functions-while-cleaning-corpus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why DocumentTermMatrix isn't working for you, but you could try using tm_map to pre-process the corpus before transforming it into a dtm. This works for me (Note that I reorder the default stoplist because otherwise it removes the stems of apostrophe words before the entire word, leaving stranded 's'):

```
corpus1 <- VCorpus(VectorSource(resume1$dat))

reorder.stoplist <- c(grep("[']", stopwords('english'), value = TRUE), 
                      stopwords('english')[!(1:length(stopwords('english')) %in% grep("[']", stopwords('english')))])

corpus1 <- tm_map(corpus1, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus1 <- tm_map(corpus1, removeWords, reorder.stoplist)
corpus1 <- tm_map(corpus1, removePunctuation)
corpus1 <- tm_map(corpus1, removeNumbers)
corpus1 <- tm_map(corpus1, stripWhitespace)

corpus1 <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I know i might be a bit too late for a reply, but I was having a similar problem and did not find an answer easily. I hope this helps others facing the same issue.

To recreate the problem, you can use this example with two problematic text excerpts:

```
library("tm")
library("textclean")
dt <- c("Vi ville också att husmodellen skulle ” ta in” det fina älvläget så mycket som möjligt.”",
    "Det är betydligt trivsammare att jobba härifrån än att sitta och ” arbeta” i ett kontorsrum i centrum.")
```

The `dt` looks like this:

```
> dt
[1] "Vi ville också att husmodellen skulle ” ta in” det fina älvläget så mycket som möjligt.”"              
[2] "Det är betydligt trivsammare att jobba härifrån än att sitta och ” arbeta” i ett kontorsrum i centrum."
```

In my case, the problem arises because I have curly braces in the text. `removePunctuation` does not identify this type of braces as punctuation, so after applying it to my text I still have the curly braces.

```
> removePunctuation(dt)
[1] "Vi ville också att husmodellen skulle ” ta in” det fina älvläget så mycket som möjligt”"              
[2] "Det är betydligt trivsammare att jobba härifrån än att sitta och ” arbeta” i ett kontorsrum i centrum"
```

I found package `textclean` (2018) has a function that replaces the curly braces with `\"` which can then be removed using `removePunctuation`:

```
> removePunctuation(replace_curly_quote(dt))
[1] "Vi ville också att husmodellen skulle  ta in det fina älvläget så mycket som möjligt"               
[2] "Det är betydligt trivsammare att jobba härifrån än att sitta och  arbeta i ett kontorsrum i centrum"
```

If you still want help to solve the other problems you mentioned, please add a code example for your data set so we can reproduce the errors and possibly fix them.