# Quotes and hyphens not removed by tm package functions while cleaning corpus

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I'm trying to clean the corpus and I've used the typical steps, like the code below:

```
docs<-Corpus(DirSource(path))
docs<-tm_map(docs,content_transformer(tolower))
docs<-tm_map(docs,content_transformer(removeNumbers))
docs<-tm_map(docs,content_transformer(removePunctuation))
docs<-tm_map(docs,removeWords,stopwords('en'))
docs<-tm_map(docs,stripWhitespace)
docs<-tm_map(docs,stemDocument)
dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
```

Yet when I inspect the matrix there are few words that come with quotes, such as:
"we" 
"company"
"code
guidelines"
-known
-accelerated

It seems that the words themselves are inside the quotes but when I try to run removePunctuation code again it doesn't work. Also there are some words with bullets in front of that I also can't remove.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand 'reproducible example'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I used the code above for a document that contained the sentence : 'For purposes of this Agreement, “Separation from Service Date”  shall mean the date of the Executive’s separation from service within the meaning of Section 409A(a)(2)(i)(A) of the Code and determined in accordance with the default rules under Section 409A of the Code'. Still doesn't clean properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`removePunctuation` uses `gsub('[[:punct:]]','',x)` i.e. removes symbols: `!"#$%&'()*+, \-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~`. To remove other symbols, like typographic quotes or bullet signs (or any other), declare your own transformation function:

```
removeSpecialChars <- function(x) gsub("“•”","",x)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeSpecialChars)
```

Or you can go further and remove everything that is not alphanumerical symbol or space:

```
removeSpecialChars <- function(x) gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]","",x)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeSpecialChars)
```

Comment: I used the code above for a document that contained the sentence : 'For purposes of this Agreement, “Separation from Service Date”  shall mean the date of the Executive’s separation from service within the meaning of Section 409A(a)(2)(i)(A) of the Code and determined in accordance with the default rules under Section 409A of the Code'. Still doesn't clean properly.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's typographic quotes. They aren't part of POSIX punctuation character class. Edited my answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: The `stringi` package allows you to implement much better definitions of quotes that include the "curly" and "smart" quotes that pop up in so much text. See `?stringi-search-charclass` and look at the `P` class union. More general and more cross-platform than the POSIX definitions.

Answer (score 1):

A better constructed tokenizer will handle this automatically.  Try this:

```
> require(quanteda)
> text <- c("Enjoying \"my time\".", "Single 'air quotes'.")
> toktexts <- tokenize(toLower(text), removePunct = TRUE, removeNumbers = TRUE)
> toktexts
[[1]]
[1] "enjoying" "my"       "time"    

[[2]]
[1] "single" "air"    "quotes"

attr(,"class")
[1] "tokenizedTexts" "list"          
> dfm(toktexts, stem = TRUE, ignoredFeatures = stopwords("english"), verbose = FALSE)
Creating a dfm from a tokenizedTexts object ...
   ... indexing 2 documents
   ... shaping tokens into data.table, found 6 total tokens
   ... stemming the tokens (english)
   ... ignoring 174 feature types, discarding 1 total features (16.7%)
   ... summing tokens by document
   ... indexing 5 feature types
   ... building sparse matrix
   ... created a 2 x 5 sparse dfm
   ... complete. Elapsed time: 0.016 seconds.
Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 5 features.
2 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
       features
docs    air enjoy quot singl time
  text1   0     1    0     0    1
  text2   1     0    1     1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @cyberj0g requires a small modification for latest version of `tm` (0.6).
Updated code can be written as follow:

```
removeSpecialChars <- function(x) gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]","",x)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(removeSpecialChars))
```

Thank you @cyberj0g for working code